# How to write a cron job ( Scheduled task ) in spring web flux?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-webflux, cron-task, reactor

I am implementing forget password feature in spring web flux application and where I am sending an OTP with a expiration of 5 min upfront. So I want to invalidate them by executing a cron job every 2 seconds.

Though this is a web flux project I want to test by writing a hello world as a cron job at first like this.

I added **@EnableScheduling** in starter main class and i have written a test class like.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * *")
    public Disposable invalidateOtp(){

       return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
           return "Hello";
       }).subscribe();

    }
```

But I would say this method does not execute after every 2 seconds. Can anyone suggest me why?

Comment: what version of spring are you using?  You'll need 5.3 or higher for improved cron expressions: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions

Comment: @billjamesdev I added System.out.println("version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion()); in the main method and i checked and it saying my version is 5.3.18.

Comment: Not enough info. Is that method is part of some bean? How really do you test? Such a method call is going to be performed in other thread from main JUnit one, so there has to be some barrier to before verification or some timing verification.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, No this is not a part of bean, This is a simple test method. As this is a cron, i started the app in debug mode and put a debug point to check weather the method calling after 10s

Comment: Then it’s not correct. If it is not the bean method then Spring doesn’t know that such a method has to be proxies and exposed respectively . Also: if it is unit test , it cannot be initiated when you start the app. You definitely have to start a test class manually or vie build tool task.

Comment: @ArtemBilan,  yes. You gave me the point. the class where i wrote this snippet marked as a service bean. So it is working now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I forget to annotate my service class @Service. Otherwise spring will not found any bean.

Answer (score -1):

Here is very good article about how to run Scheduled tasks with cron expression or with fixed rate or fixed delay: [The @Scheduled Annotation in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks). This should give you all you need. However, At some point I felt that all options provided in Spring boot were not convinient enough especially for human readability of the params. You have to specify time in milliseconds or with cron-expression which is not very easily readable. So, I wanted to be able specify time like "9m" for 9 minutes or "3h" for 3 hours and so forth. So, I wrote my own background task scheduler that can easily be used with Spring boot. I published it in Open source library called MgntUtils which is written and maintained by me. Here is a [Javadoc page](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/backgroundrunner/package-summary.html) that explains my idea and how to use the feature. (This is part of MgntUtils library javadoc) You can get the library as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on the [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with javadoc and source-code included). On the github you can look in the package: `com.mgnt.lifecycle.management.backgroundrunner.example`. That package contains complete working example of 2 scheduled tasks. If you download the source you can just run them out of the box and see how they work

Comment: Actually i annotated class as a service bean and then it is working as what i want.